# react prop value updates when state value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have this react component that renders a child and passes one prop:

```
const Parent: FunctionComponent = ({ route }) => {
    const { routeProp } = route.params;
    const { passThisProp } = routeProp;

    return (
        <Child prop={passThisProp} />
    )
}

// these functions are in different files

const Child: FunctionComponent = ({ prop }) => {
    const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState(prop)

    function updateProp(prop: string[][]) {
        const arr = [...prop];
        arr[i][j] = count.toString();
        return arr;
    }

    return ...
}
```

Inside of the Child component I have a mapped through `prop` which is an array of string arrays. The issue is when I update locally or `localValue` the `prop` value that I passed also updated.

I assume that shouldn't be happening. Why is the state change of my local variable changing the parents prop it passed? Firstly I'm only assigning localValue to have an `initial` state of whatever value `prop` has, right?

How are they getting linked? I've never seen this before. I've checked over everything and I'm not updating the `prop` anywhere. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: i dont know what are you doing by this code but you can try  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState([...props]);

Comment: yeah that didn't work not sure

Comment: yes it for simple array for multidimensional array you need to destruct all level to clone the array... there is some methods to clone an array : var newArray = currentArray.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
});
 or var newArray = currentArray.map(arr => arr.slice());  or with trick var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current approach to cloning is only cloning the outer array but is not cloning the inner ones. Clone the inner ones so `Child` gets its own clone:

```js
// Clone entire 2D array
const arr = prop.map((innerArr) => [...innerArr]);
```

or you can clone the array before creating the local value:

```js
// Clone entire 2D array before setting as local state
const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState(
  prop.map((innerArr) => [...innerArr])
);
```

Comment: okay but it's able to update both?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "update both?"

Comment: as in the parent prop is being updated but so is the localValue

Comment: You can clone the array before setting it as local state.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to clone before setting local state.